# C# Oracle SQL Connection is extremely slow on large data-sets

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, oracle

Thanks for reading!

I'm running into an issue where my connection to Oracle (2.5 million records) starts off 'relatively speedy' and then slows down immensely.

Here's how I'm creating the connection: (This is a synchronization between two databases, my local DB could be Oracle/SQL Server/MySQL--who knows?)

```
private static void ImportSomeData(string sql, DbConnection connection, int batchSize)
{
        var command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = sql;
        //Throw an exception here if needed
        var results = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (results.HasRows)
        {
          //...read here. 
        }
}
```

The batch size refers to the EntityFramework, I'm holding a connection for ~ 200 rows and then recreating (OutOfMemory errors are quite possible, and I'm just trying to see what our optimal size is. (I should note I've used 200-20000 as batch sizes before recreating the `IRepository` and it seems to have very little effect other than memory errors on the upper size).

Here's an example of the logs:

```
[INFO]  [2015-11-24 12:34:21]   Imported 1000 Clients
[INFO]  [2015-11-24 12:34:24]   Imported 2000 Clients
[INFO]  [2015-11-24 12:34:26]   Imported 3000 Clients
[INFO]  [2015-11-24 12:34:29]   Imported 4000 Clients
[INFO]  [2015-11-24 12:34:33]   Imported 5000 Clients
[INFO]  [2015-11-24 12:34:37]   Imported 6000 Clients
[INFO]  [2015-11-24 12:34:41]   Imported 7000 Clients
[INFO]  [2015-11-24 12:34:45]   Imported 8000 Clients
[INFO]  [2015-11-24 12:34:49]   Imported 9000 Clients
[INFO]  [2015-11-24 12:34:55]   Imported 10000 Clients
[INFO]  [2015-11-24 12:35:00]   Imported 11000 Clients
[INFO]  [2015-11-24 12:35:05]   Imported 12000 Clients
[INFO]  [2015-11-24 12:35:11]   Imported 13000 Clients
[INFO]  [2015-11-24 12:35:17]   Imported 14000 Clients
[INFO]  [2015-11-24 12:35:23]   Imported 15000 Clients
[INFO]  [2015-11-24 12:35:30]   Imported 16000 Clients
[INFO]  [2015-11-24 12:35:37]   Imported 17000 Clients
[INFO]  [2015-11-24 12:35:44]   Imported 18000 Clients
[INFO]  [2015-11-24 12:35:51]   Imported 19000 Clients
[INFO]  [2015-11-24 12:35:59]   Imported 20000 Clients
[INFO]  [2015-11-24 12:36:06]   Imported 21000 Clients
[INFO]  [2015-11-24 12:36:14]   Imported 22000 Clients
[INFO]  [2015-11-24 12:36:21]   Imported 23000 Clients
[INFO]  [2015-11-24 12:36:31]   Imported 24000 Clients
[INFO]  [2015-11-24 12:36:42]   Imported 25000 Clients
```

I'm seeing this behavior on three different systems. If you look closely at the timestamps you'll see that as we move further and further into the resultset the time to process 1000 rows starts to creep up pretty quickly and it doesn't seem to level off. There's obviously a lot of places to start troubleshooting this (and it might not be Oracle) but I'm wondering if there might be a better approach to this (via a cursor/temp table, index...really I'm open to anything here).

```
--Example from the server:
[INFO]  [2015-11-20 11:09:18]   Imported 1000 Clients
[INFO]  [2015-11-20 11:10:45]   Imported 2000 Clients
...
[INFO]  [2015-11-20 18:06:45]   Imported 508000 Clients
[INFO]  [2015-11-20 18:08:36]   Imported 509000 Clients
```

Any thoughts on this would be appreciated. I could see a situation where the local connection in the target application is to blame but I see this same behavior over result-sets that already have the records in the database (starting quick and slowing down after the initial push) which is why I'm wondering if there's a better way to pull in this record by record comparison.

I would accept punting the EntityFramework out of the application as an acceptable solution, we were just looking for something that makes the data-import a bit more readable for the client systems. No one here has any other ideas on how to speed this up.

**EDIT**
Some of the SQL was requested, here's a (not real) example thanks to an NDA:

```
SELECT
  a.A AS Field1,
  a.B AS Field2,
  CASE a.C
  WHEN 'StringNum2' THEN 1
  WHEN 'StringNum2' THEN 2
   ...
  ELSE -1 AS Field3,
  --Another case statement
  a.D AS Field9
  ...
  a.G AS Field10
FROM 
  ImportTableNoJoins a
```

Comment: Sounds like a DBA Issue.. do you have a `DBA on Staff` this could be for a number of reason from `Network being slow, all the way down to Bad Indexes`... can someone run the profiler or a cost plan..?

Comment: This doesn't sound like an Oracle database problem.  I don't think I've ever seen a query where the time gets progressively slower for each  row.  You could rule it out by posting the explain plan - find the SQL_ID with `select * from gv$sql where lower(sql_text) like '%importtablenojoins%';`, then use it in `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(sql_id => '$SQL_ID'));`.

Comment: @JonHeller Thanks for the tip. I agree this doesn't look like any behavior I've ever seen from Oracle (or SQL Server)

Answer (score 1):

Do you notice any improvement if you ensure Dispose is called?

```
private static void ImportSomeData(string sql, DbConnection connection, int batchSize)
{
    using(var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = sql;
        //Throw an exception here if needed
        var results = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (results.HasRows)
        {
          //...read here. 
        }
    }
}
```

Also, could you please show us the SQL command text that you are using?  Here are some ideas on SQL Query optimization: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/55505/SQL-Query-Optimization-FAQ-Part-With-video-expla

As well, you could try using performance counters to pinpoint the problem in C# code or some sort of tool to profile your Oracle database: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42001/NET-Best-Practice-No-Using-performance-counters

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I noticed an extremely minor improvement (1-3%) with Dispose being called every ~ 200 or so rows so there's a possibility there was a `List` that was being iterated over. I've edited my answer to show an example of the SQL, but it is protected by non-disclosure so I needed to obfuscate it a bit.